# Change position or order of a field in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to change the order of a field using only javascript or jquery without access to jsp. Say I have 2 fields on my jsp

First Name
Last Name

Can I make it as below withput touching the jsp code? and by using javascript

Last Name
First Name

Comment: Can you offer clarification on 'field', what have you tried?

Comment: you can do it even with CSS without the need of javascript

Comment: <form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: I have a html something like the above. I want to change the order of fields, Like Last Name and then First Name

Comment: You can do it, of course, but should it be done on page load, or some other event? If on load - not sure WHY (because you can order elements how you wish, on server side, and just print them)?

Answer (score 2):

Using your sample code

```
<form action="demo_form.asp"> 
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br> 
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

If I like to change the order, say while displaying the form, I'll use CSS as one of the comments suggested. So the HTML can be:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="demo_form.asp">
        <div class="fname-holder">
            <input type="text" name="fname">
            <label for="fname">First name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="lname-holder">
            <input type="text" name="lname">
            <label for="lname">Last name</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Please note added divs and label tags. 
And the CSS to change vertical ordering can be something like this using display table:

```
container {
    display: table;
}
.fname-holder {
    display: table-footer-group;
}
.lname-holder {
    display: table-header-group;
}
label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/omidfi/p3s863y0/) a jsfiddle to try it

Answer (score 0):

Also the most straight forward could be,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").html(' Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br> First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br> <input type="submit" value="Submit"> ');
});

</script>
```